# How to add a link to back of the pass which calls another app in iPhone or iPod

Tags: ios, web-services, passbook

I created a pass for passbook already. which field can I put link and that link call another app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to get the Adam ID for the App, then add an `associatedStoreIdentifiers` key to your pass.json.

E.g. to include the Google Maps App, add the following to the root of your pass.json:

```
"associatedStoreIdentifiers":[585027354]
```

You can get the Adam ID from the link to the App in the iTunes store.

`https://itunes.apple.com/app/id585027354`

Comment: How to get that adam id of an app ?

Comment: Can I get Adam ID for the app that I just create (not yet put in App store)?

Comment: No - not possible - the App has to be published already.  This is because there is no Passbook sandbox.  Making it possible to be able to distribute a pass with a Private App could lead to a bad user experience

Comment: What about the link to web page, can I add it to the back of pass ?

Comment: Yes - any url that you enter into a backfield will automatically become clickable but you cannot use `<a>` HTML tags.  See [this pass](https://pass.is/ZxTR9U) for an example of how you can use links to top-up a stored value pass with PayPal

Comment: do you have other solution to add link of web page ? I go to the link for example above already, but how can I add any link without using <a> ?

Comment: You can't use <a>.  Just put the naked link into the field. `{"key":"b4","value":"This Pass has been created using the PassKit Pass Designer. http://create.passkit.com","label":"Powered by PassKit"}]}`

Comment: Hi how i can add more details in URL, Can I open the oder page of my app on click the open link?